# Alternative of geth Ethereum Node

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, rinkeby

I am new to Ethereum block-chain.I am trying to syncing ethereum node in testnet(**Rinkeby**).I am using HDD for syncing **geth** ethereum node.I know it very slow to syncing.

So,Is it any alternative of **geth** which will syncing data fast with HDD??

Comment: Was my answer able to help?

Comment: No,I tried to syncing **ethereum geth node** with **--fast** and **cache**.I am syncing data last 5 hours.Till now **eth.blockNumber** is 0 and I funded some ether requesting address.But when I check it geth console command **eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])** so it shows 0.It means ethereum  node not sync now.

Answer (score 2):

[Parity](https://parity.io) is considered the fastest and most advanced Ethereum client.

Answer (score 0):

I will quote my answer from [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48469/ethereum-light-node-light-vs-cache-vs-fastsync/48472#48472) about the different kinds of syncing that are available, difference in speed and resulting information. While it is not a direct answer to your question, I think it will help with the root issue:

> - "Full" Sync: Gets the block headers, the block bodies, and validates every element from genesis block.
> - Fast Sync: Gets the block headers, the block bodies, it processes no transactions until current block - 64(*). Then it gets a snapshot state and goes like a full synchronization.
> - Light Sync: Gets only the current state. To verify elements, it needs to ask to full (archive) nodes for the corresponding tree leaves.
>
> **Then an extra piece of information on cache and how it can used to go fast from [this response](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48469/ethereum-light-node-light-vs-cache-vs-fastsync/48472#48472):**
>
> A 50% speed increase is possible just by increasing the cache.
>
> If you are starting from the beginning, use: geth --fast --cache=1024
>
> If you already have some of the blockchain, use: geth --cache=1024
>
> Depending on your RAM, you can also try with higher values, like --cache=2048.

Answer (score 0):

> ... I know it very slow to syncing...

In my experience, one of the biggest factors in getting geth to sync is having **port 30303 open properly** (i.e. it's the default anyway, but you can specify *--port "30303"*). This is the port that allows other nodes on the same blockchain to find your node (tcp/udp). If they cannot, then you have less chance of being found by "healthy" up-
to-date nodes for yours to sync with.

Is this port open to the Internet?

Answer (score -2):

**Disclaimer : I belong to the Blockgum it self, I am here introducing system that would be helpful for people using Geth and having hard time with lack features, ie Tracking deposits, processing withdrawals and Various stats monitoring.**

GitHub : https://github.com/blockgum/blockgum

What is blockgum , It is alternative for GETH + Moralis , as Its all in one solution for multiple chains .

Using one server and client you can install any EVM chain multiple chains same time.

**Product Description**:
Are you looking for a comprehensive and user-friendly solution to manage and track your digital assets on multiple EVM chains? Look no further than Blockgum! Our advanced HDWallet technology allows you to generate unlimited addresses with just one private key, and our derivation path is the same as Metamask. Plus, all geth features are already included.

Blockgum can track transfers and deposits of network coins or tokens on any EVM network, and it can run multiple networks at the same time. This means that you can use a single address per customer for all EVM networks, such as ETH, Matic, FTM, Avax, BNB or any other EVM network listed on https://chainlist.org. Our mobile client connects to the Blockgum server app and allows you to manage and track everything, with tools like emergency restart/shutdown, address generation and tracking, deposit tracking, withdrawal from main account or any user account, and more. Plus, the mobile app offers a secure login using QR, so you can scan the QR code from the server CLI.

On the server side, Blockgum offers unlimited address creation, support for any chain or multiple chains at the same time, no syncing required as it connects with Public RPC, super secure request to server are encrypted using **JWT HS256**, constant deposit tracking and deposit records in DB (**MongoDB**), withdrawals processing and records, deposit movement to main account, token monitoring and many more features.

Blockgum is ideal for a wide range of use cases, such as **crypto exchanges supporting multiple chains, ICO/IDOs, wallet service providers, online stores** accepting crypto as payment, and people using Ethereum Web3, Geth or Moralis. And with our REST APIs, you can connect to any server or client-side app.

We also provide complete Blockgum documentation, and our installation tool allows you to set up Blockgum in just a few steps, as quick as an hour max.

With over **378 mainnet** and 300 testnets supported by Blockgum, including popular chains like ETH, Matic, BNB, Avax, FTM, MOVR, CRO, HT, TOMO, and KLAY, you can easily support any EVM network by simply adding its RPC (HTTP/WSS) in chains.json. And with our commitment to privacy, Blockgum is an independent server application that does not share any information with anyone, including us. All we know is the MD5 of the Extended master public key.

For more information, check out the video at to see how easy it is to install Blockgum on your server.
Blockgum Server
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6qBnSG80rVQ
Blockgum Mobile
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jaL4HY-MASw

Thank you

Comment: Your answer is a bit too long, and it looks like an advertisement. You listed a bunch of capabilities but never mention what is it. It looks like a blockchain api and wallet provider. It doesn't seem a direct replacement for geth as a network client.

Comment: +Hi Ismael, Yes is replacement as Geth does following activities , address generation + transaction signing .  It does not do following 1. HD wallet Generation [ One Extended master key for all like metamask] , 2. Support multiple chains with single app. 3. Deposit detect 4. Withdrawal Tracking 5. Stats management 6. Optional move to main address [Like exchanges do] 6. One mobile client to manage all activity . 7. Take down or close app any moment using mobile app. 8. many more and counting . I have been using geth from years now .and developed blockgum after seeing its short comings.

Comment: Sorry, but you are writing and advertisement. The official site doesn't provide any documentation, can't download anything without registration, there's no public repository. When I click "Get Started" it redirect to an empty page that says "coming soon".

Comment: For public data Blockgum connects with other Feeds ie , Infura, Other Geth or EVM feeds. You can configure multiple feeds as at a time as it switches between multiple feeds when reading WSS/HTTP rpc data.  Also when geth node server is wiped or deleted for some reason , funds can be lost as every time a new account is created , new Keystore.json has to be backed up, But with Blockgum blockgup of Privatekey is never required. It uses xPRV [ Derived from your Seed phrases derived from m/44'/60'/0'/0] and xPub . Keys are encrypted once stored.

Comment: Yes , Its being updated . Dashboard should be available in 2 days max. I am working on it my self .  :)

Comment: Dashboard is now available. App is public now .  Will add more videos either on youtube or https://blockgum.com