# Fast sync ain't fast enough

Tags: go-ethereum, fast-sync

I'm running geth with

```
--syncmode=fast --cache=4096 --maxpeers=50
```

My laptop runs like crazy, but it's never able to reach the top of the chain (blocks are at the moment been created ~ once every 14 secs).

I'm running this from the geth console:

```
function status() {
   console.log("diff states");
   console.log(eth.syncing.knownStates-eth.syncing.pulledStates);
   console.log("diff blocks");
   console.log(eth.syncing.highestBlock-eth.syncing.currentBlock);
   console.log("peers");
   console.log(net.peerCount);
};
```

I'm getting something like this:

```
> status()
diff states
23717
diff blocks
104
peers
12
```

The diff blocks oscillates from 60-120, but in never converges to 0.  So I'm never able to get to the last block.

Since I'm in fast sync mode, that means my accounts always show zero.. can't send / receive funds.

What am I misunderstanding / doing wrong here?

Should I go full node instead..?  That would show correct state of my accounts even if not fully synchronized, right?

Or should I go parity instead of get?  It's been a while since I last played around with ethereum..

Or am I just being impatient..?

Help appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Details of my hw:

- Dell XPS13
- 7.4 GB of memory
- i7-3537U
- 500 GB SSD drive

I decided to go full-node, but now the geth client just died because of insufficient memory..

```
heinä 03 19:53:59 sampsa-xps-old geth[7365]: INFO [07-03|19:53:59.745] Imported new chain segment               blocks=198   txs=7184  mgas=423.091  elapsed=8.011s    mgasps=52.812  number=3804902 hash="3a51df…e690ff" age=3y1mo2w  dirty=625.69MiB
heinä 03 19:54:07 sampsa-xps-old geth[7365]: INFO [07-03|19:54:07.757] Imported new chain segment               blocks=60    txs=1919  mgas=130.876  elapsed=8.011s    mgasps=16.335  number=3804962 hash="1e617b…2cf7f8" age=3y1mo2w  dirty=622.71MiB
heinä 03 19:54:11 sampsa-xps-old geth[7365]: fatal error: runtime: out of memory
heinä 03 19:54:12 sampsa-xps-old geth[7365]: runtime stack:
heinä 03 19:54:12 sampsa-xps-old geth[7365]: runtime.throw(0x123d678, 0x16)
heinä 03 19:54:12 sampsa-xps-old geth[7365]:         /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:774 +0x72
```

I changed cache to 2048 and restarted the client, but know I get a lot of this:

```
heinä 03 23:14:07 sampsa-xps-old geth[2278]: WARN [07-03|23:14:07.195] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=3ed8bf9ac1074322 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid: missing parent"                                                  
heinä 03 23:14:08 sampsa-xps-old geth[2278]: WARN [07-03|23:14:08.480] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=b31577aeb5194851 err="action from bad peer ignored"                                                                     
heinä 03 23:14:11 sampsa-xps-old geth[2278]: WARN [07-03|23:14:11.032] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=0c6253589a8d244d err="action from bad peer ignored"
heinä 03 23:14:17 sampsa-xps-old geth[2278]: WARN [07-03|23:14:17.606] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=d9f9252151cde7bc err=timeout
heinä 03 23:14:28 sampsa-xps-old geth[2278]: WARN [07-03|23:14:28.142] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=f2e666172f3b92ee err=timeout
heinä 03 23:15:12 sampsa-xps-old geth[2278]: WARN [07-03|23:15:12.855] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=91baf3867f5d09eb err="retrieved hash chain is invalid: missing parent"
heinä 03 23:15:25 sampsa-xps-old geth[2278]: WARN [07-03|23:15:25.233] Checkpoint challenge timed out, dropping id=e2be7549d1dc2d45 conn=dyndial addr=54.169.18.25:23232  type=Geth/v1.9.15-stable-0f77f34b/linux-amd64/go1.14.4
heinä 03 23:15:59 sampsa-xps-old geth[2278]: WARN [07-03|23:15:59.248] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=5792e16bd9014bc1 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid: missing parent"
heinä 03 23:16:34 sampsa-xps-old geth[2278]: WARN [07-03|23:16:34.452] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=f0dbb55b701d1978 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid: timeout"
heinä 03 23:16:35 sampsa-xps-old geth[2278]: WARN [07-03|23:16:35.668] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=887c72a99e4b9301 err="action from bad peer ignored"
```

..so the blockchains gone sour?  Geth doesn't seem like a stable program.

But, coming back to my original question:

Why the distance from the last processed block to the newest existing block didn't converge (it fluctuated)..  Is it because my laptops processing can't keep up with it..?  Or is it because my network connection can't download the blocks fast enought (I have 10 mbps)?  What could be the reason?

Could it be that I don't get enough peers to get the blocks rapid enough?  I usually can get just max 13 peers.

Comment: Found similar things here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16796

Comment: When you say "never", how long did you try to let it fast sync?

Comment: several days.  As I explained, the block difference does not converge..  people talk of similar issues in that github ticket..

Comment: I'm suspecting several days isn't long enough... Just to check: you're running an SSD and not a HDD?

Comment: +1 as @Richard. The SSD has been added to the wiki https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-get-a-geth-node-to-download-the-blockchain-quickly/4210#4210

Comment: Thanks. Please look at the updates in the question.

Comment: Went full-node, added 20GB swap, opened port 30303 in NAT table.  Will let you know then..

Answer (score 0):

So, I never got the fast sync working (not sure why), so I went full node instead.

My experience / checklist is summarized here: https://github.com/elsampsa/home-ethereum

As of June-August 2020, the syncing took more than a month and the blockchain occupies around 850 GB.

Now sending transactions works like a charm (in ~ 30 seconds).  Viva Ethereum.